# Questions on IDFA - availability and uniqueness

Tags: idfa

I have some questions on Apple's IDFA:

1. Is this ID unique across apps on the same device? When a user resets iOS device, does the ID change?
2. When a user resets iOS device, does the ID change?
3. If the user disables IDFA tracking, can we still retrieve the ID from app? 
   What is Android's counterpart ID's name?
4. What is Android's counterpart ID's name? 
   Does it behave the same way as IDFA to the above 3 questions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The ID is Unique across apps on the same device, it changes when user resets iOS device.
If we disables the IDFA tracking, we can't retrieve the ID.
And I don't know the Android.